# How to query for NON compliant Azure Policies in Kusto query language on Log Analytic Workspace

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-policy

I've been trying to return resources that are not compliant with my built in Policy of having an Azure Active Directory administrator provisioned for SQL servers (https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F1f314764-cb73-4fc9-b863-8eca98ac36e9).

The goal is whenever there is a SQL deployment that is not associated with an Azure Active Directory Admin, an alert should be sent by email. But I been unable to write the correct Log Analytics query to actually return NON COMPLIANTS. I am very confused on what exactly the property "isComplianceCheck" means because it is false for all resources even ones that are compliant with the policy. I've looked at blogs https://mohitgoyal.co/2019/10/11/using-azure-log-analytics-alerts-for-non-compliant-azure-resources/ and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-create-azure-monitor-alerts-for-non-compliant-azure/ba-p/713466 neither of them have the correct, up to date syntax. So what is the correct query syntax to return NON COMPLIANTS?

Other Questions: Tips for organizing the Activity Log? I got 20+ entries from a single SQL deployment and it is very hard to sort through what is what.

Comment: Azure Policy no longer logs compliant and non-compliant resource scans in Activity Log hence why those documents are out of date. Compliance information is in Azure Resource Graph to query on.

Comment: @Kemley, where did you get this information from? Per Microsoft documentation isComplianceCheck is one of the fields which shall be returned